# SQL how to rollback transaction if bulk insert fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a query to delete all rows from a table and then bulk insert from a txt. If there is a problem with the bulk insert  I don't want to loose my old data so I want to rollback the transaction.

This is what I've been trying:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE Users_Login
BULK INSERT Users_Login FROM '\\STRMV1234\ - Some_Table.txt'  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 'ACP')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

However if there is an error I'm losing everything from the table. I also tried the code below, which doesn't work either:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        DELETE Users_Login
        BULK INSERT Users_Login FROM '\\STRMV1234\ - Some_Table.txt'  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 'ACP')
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You need to post the error, some errors do not hit the try catch block.

Comment: Move the `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT` outside of the your `TRY...CATCH`

Comment: Most likely the try..catch won't catch a bulk insert error because most errors would hit over severity of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give this a try.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM Users_Login
BULK INSERT Users_Login FROM '\\STRMV1234\ - Some_Table.txt'  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 'ACP')

IF @@ERROR = 0  
BEGIN
COMMIT
PRINT 'GOOD'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
PRINT 'BAD'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
Begin Try

    Begin Tran
    Truncate Table data
    BULK INSERT data FROM '...\data.txt'  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 1, CODEPAGE = 'ACP')

    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 Commit
    print 'ok'
End Try
Begin Catch
    print 'error'
    if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 Rollback
End Catch
```

Comment: hi Julien, your code prints "ok". However if I run only the truncate-bulk insert lines I get the error: `Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 4 (LogoutDate).`

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is `XACT_ABORT` which basically turns on sane error handling. The default one is insane/unpredictable.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE ...
BULK INSERT ...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Any error kills the batch and transaction.